# How to setup Synology mail server (not MailServerPlus) under noip.com

Tags: synology, dynamic-dns

I have Synology server running with router Netgear R7000. R7000 has a domain register under noip.com with domain: hello.ddns.net.

I want to setup MailServer (not MailServerPlus which is paid server) under my domain: hello.ddns.net.

I set up Synology MailServer according to: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uC1iosN3-8I

Setup MX record under noip.com for my domain: "hello.ddns.net" according to: https://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/receive-email-domain-name-console/

```
(pseudo acc and domain)

Synology acc: helloacc
Domain: hello.ddns.net
Yahoo acc: myacc@yahoo.com
```

I send a email from yahoo account, and I got error in Synology webmail client.

```
Reporting-MTA: dns; hello.ddns.net
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 0AC981520E7E
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; helloacc@hello.ddns.net
Arrival-Date: Wed,  3 Apr 2019 01:29:56 -0700 (PDT)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; myacc@yahoo.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;myacc@yahoo.com
Action: failed
Status: 4.4.1
Diagnostic-Code: X-Postfix; connect to     mta7.am0.yahoodns.net[67.195.229.59]:25:
Connection timed out
```

Questions:

1) What's missing?

2) Is it possible to make this work?

Comment: Do you have firewall configured on DSM?

Comment: yes. then, what port should check? thank you.